# Button taking the entire frame even with pre-defined width and height

Tags: tkinter

even though  I have already defined the width and height of the buttons they seem to take the entire frame on their own. I am unable to understand the possible reason behind it.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

main_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="gray")
main_frame.grid(sticky='news')

f2 = tk.Frame(main_frame) # create a frame inside the main frame to attach scroll bar to
f2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='nw', columnspan=3) # for north, west

f2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
f2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

c2 = tk.Canvas(f2, bg="orange")
c2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

hsb = tk.Scrollbar(f2, orient="horizontal", command=c2.xview, width=10)
hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we') # west-east
c2.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set)

f2_c2 = tk.Frame(c2, bg="yellow")
c2.create_window((0, 0), window=f2_c2, anchor='nw')

b1 = tk.Button(f2_c2, relief='raised', width=200, height=200)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0 ,padx=5, pady=5)
b2 = tk.Button(f2_c2, relief='raised', width=200, height=200)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
b3 = tk.Button(f2_c2, relief='raised', width=200, height=200)
b3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

f2_c2.update_idletasks()
c2.configure(scrollregion=c2.bbox("all"), width=400, height=400)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

is there a workaround or is it something i am missing ?

Comment: Note that the `width` is in characters and `height` is in lines for a button without image.  So you are creating big buttons.  Change those options to, for example, `width=10, height=2` to see the difference.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.. It seems to work how its supposed to now. But still don't understand why it was covering the whole frame even though i set their height and width to almost half the frame in which i put them.

Comment: Once again, `width` and `height` options _**are not in pixels**_ for a button *without a image*.  They are in **number of characters** and **number of lines** correspondingly. So for your case, you created *200 characters width and 200 lines height* buttons.

Comment: Yes, after fiddling with it a bit I finally understood what was happening. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` and `height` attributes of a button (and a few others) are documented to be in units of average-sized characters unless there is an image on the button. Thus, when you set the width to 200, that's 200 *characters*. If one character is 16 pixels wide, you're setting the width of the button to 3200 pixels.

If you want to specify the width in pixels, you can add an invisible pixel to the button.

```
img = tk.PhotoImage()
b1 = tk.Button(f2_c2, relief='raised', width=200, height=200, image=img, compound="c")
b2 = tk.Button(f2_c2, relief='raised', width=200, height=200, image=img, compound="c")
b3 = tk.Button(f2_c2, relief='raised', width=200, height=200, image=img, compound="c")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#BUTTON
image_1 = tk.PhotoImage()
button_1 = tk.Button(f2_c2, relief='raised', width=200, height=200, image=image_1, compound="c")
```